# Javascript loop through objects in objects

Tags: javascript, object, loops

I'm trying to retrieve only `word` from inside each new instance of the `newEntry` object. It displays in the console every time I add a new word, but not when I assign it to `.innerHTML`.  Can anyone help?

Full code:

```
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        #output { height: auto;}
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Array to contain words
        var wordList = Array();

        // word list constructor
        function addWord(word) {
            this.word = word;
            this.description = "a description of the word";
            this.entryDate = "01.02.2012";
            this.userName = "John Doe";

            var newEntry = {
                word: word,
                description: description,
                entryDate: entryDate,
                userName: userName 
            };

            wordList[wordList.length] = newEntry;           
        };

        // collect data from form
        function getFormData() {
            var results = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
            addWord(results);

            var data = '<ul>';
            var numObjects = "Number of words = " + wordList.length; 

            for (var x in wordList) {
                var wordSet = wordList[x];
                for (var item in wordSet.word[x]) {
                    console.log(wordSet.word);                   
                    data += "<li><a href='#'>" + wordSet.word + "</a></li>";    

                };
            };
            data += "</ul>";
            document.getElementById("Objects").innerHTML = numObjects;  
            document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML = data;                 
            // console.log(wordList);  

        };

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <form id="form_id" name="form_name" action="" method="post">
        <p><label for="text">Enter words:<br/></label>
        <input type="textarea" id="textbox" />
        <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="getFormData()"
    </form>

    <ul id="Output"></ul>   
    <div id="Objects"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the content of the 'output' div each time. You could try changing

```
            document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML = wordSet.word;
```

to

```
            document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML += wordSet.word;
```

Then you should see the proper output (sans styling, or line breaks, of course).

*** Further update ***

You're using your arrays in some funky ways. You might want to just declare your array as a literal and then use the push method to append the entry to the array. For iterating over the array you should probably use the standard for loop [eg: for (var i = 0; i < arr. length; ++i) kind of syntax, or the array forEach syntax (if supported by your browser). for in will iterate over all the properties of the object, and while technically safe for an array, is somewhat of an advised-against practice.

Also, there's really no reason to assign properties into 'this' if you are just going to wrap the elements in JSON and stuff them in the list.

I'd recommend something like the following:

```
       // Array to contain words
        var wordList = [];

        // append word to word list
        function addWord(word) {
            var newEntry = {
                word: word,
                description: "a description of the word",
                entryDate: "01.02.2012",
                userName: "John Doe" 
            };

            wordList.push(newEntry);           
        };
```

Then when interacting with your word list you would say:

```
for (var i = 0; i < wordList.length; ++i) {
    var wordEntry = wordList[i];
...
}
```

a la:

```
/ collect data from form
            function getFormData() {
                var results = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
                addWord(results);

                var data = '<ul>';

                for (var i = 0; i < wordList.length; ++i) {
                    var wordEntry = wordList[i];
                    // I removed the inner for loop here, as you were iterating over all
                    // the proerties of the word string. This would loop for all the
                    // individual characters, as well as all the methods on the string
                    // (e.g. charAt, indexOf, etc.) It could have been a source of
                    // problems for you, and given the original following line, would 
                    // have shown duplicate entries in the list.

                    data += "<li><a href='#'>" + wordEntry.word + "</a></li>";                     
                };
                data += "</ul>";
                document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML = data;
            };
```

Comment: Thanks Gopherkhan. I've modified the script using `+= wordSet.word` to print results as `<li>` items, but it seems to be repeating the object contents and adding them, rather than updating the list. New code is in the original post above...

Comment: Can you give an example of the data you are using? Also, if you're going to be displaying these as list items, you're going to want to wrap them in a ul or ol tag. It's probably best for you to just build up the string from the results, and then append it once. For example, in your nested for loop, you would just build up your string, and below the outer loop, you would assign it into d the dom with innerHTML.

Comment: In fact, I see what you're asking about now. Yes, since you are going to be updating the content of this div with different data, you'll want to use the string-building option I mentioned in my previous comment.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: OK so perhaps I spoke too soon. I've updated my original post to reflect your suggestions. Displaying the results of `word` seems to hang after 4 or 5 are added into the `<ul>`. I can see the Object `wordList` is actually functioning fine by displaying the length of `wordList`.

Comment: Okay. So I was focusing on your code that interacts with the dom. Looks like you're using the arrays in some funky ways. They shouldn't exactly be problematic, but they're sort of at odds with standard practice. I don't really understand the for (var item in wordSet.word[x]) line...it looks like you're treating the word string like an array? That would work essentially as a charAt function, getting you a single character at the index of X... I'll update with some other tips.

Comment: Thanks again Gopherkhan. As you probably guessed I'm a newb, and it looks like I was trying to do something in a more complicated way than necessary! Creating a new object for every new word entry was just giving me a headache when I wanted to iterate through the whole collection.

Comment: No problem. Glad to be of help! :)